# Python (Anaconda Installation)

Tags: command-line, bash, python

I have downloaded python 2.7 installer. After downloading the installer, I executed the following command in the terminal:
`/home/najam/Downloads/Anaconda2-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh`
The execution resulted in the following error:
`bash: /home/najam/Downloads/Anaconda2-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh: Permission denied`

What am I doing wrong? It'll be much helpful if step-by-step sequence of commands is posted for Anaconda's installation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to the installation script directory

```
cd /home/najam/Downloads/
```

Add execute permissions (this is the part you missed)

```
sudo chmod +x Anaconda2-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Then install

```
./Anaconda2-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Comment: then you should mark the answer as helpful,,glad it helped to,cheers!

Comment: I did already, but since my reputation is <15, so the upvote has been recorded, but not yet published

Comment: no,there is a small tick under the uprooting tab,you should tick that and it will turn green showing that the answer already satisfy you needs

Answer (score 0):

I think you should better use `bash` command because you need to give executable permission to the shell script file.

```
bash /home/najam/Downloads/Anaconda2-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Comment: Do you have a source for this claim?

Comment: -1 The official site says to use Bash, not Bourne. https://www.continuum.io/downloads#linux

Comment: You're right, it case should use bash instead of sh.

Comment: But, generally which any one betwen is not a big deal.

Comment: Because sh link to bash in linux. sh -> bach.

Comment: @SteveHan In Debian and Ubuntu, sh links to dash, not bash